# operating on embedded tuples/strings, python

Tags: python, string, tuples, nltk

say I have a tagged text (word, tag) in tuple format. i want to convert it to a string in order to make some changes to the tags. my function below only sees the last sentence in the text, i guess there is some obvious and stupid mistake which  i cant realize, so plz help to make it work on the entire text.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> tpl = [[('This', 'V'), ('is', 'V'), ('one', 'NUM'), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')], [('And', 'CNJ'), ('This', 'V'), ('is', 'V'), ('another', 'DET'), ('one', 'NUM')]]

def translate(tuple2string):
    for sent in tpl:
        t = ' '.join([nltk.tag.tuple2str(item) for item in sent])

>>> print t
    'And/CNJ This/V is/V another/DET one/NUM'
```

P.S. for those who are interested, tuple2str function is described [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/nltk/0.9.5/guides/tag.html)

**EDIT:** now i should convert it back to a tuple, having the same format. How do i do it?

```
>>> [nltk.tag.str2tuple(item) for item in t.split()]
```

the one above converts in into entire tuple, but i need embedded one (the same as in the input (`tpl`) )

**EDIT2:** well, probably it's worth to publish the entire code:

```
def translate(tpl):
    t0 = [' '.join([nltk.tag.tuple2str(item) for item in sent]) for sent in tpl] 
    for t in t0: 
        t = re.sub(r'/NUM', '/N', t) 
        t = [nltk.tag.str2tuple(item) for item in t.split()] 
    print t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> ' '.join(' '.join(nltk.tag.tuple2str(item) for item in sent) for sent in tpl)
'This/V is/V one/NUM sentence/NN ./. And/CNJ This/V is/V another/DET one/NUM'
```

**EDIT:**

If you want this to be reversible then just don't do the outer join.

```
>>> [' '.join([nltk.tag.tuple2str(item) for item in sent]) for sent in tpl]
['This/V is/V one/NUM sentence/NN ./.', 'And/CNJ This/V is/V another/DET one/NUM']
```

**EDIT 2:**

I thought we went over this already...

```
>>> [[nltk.tag.str2tuple(re.sub('/NUM', '/N', w)) for w in s.split()] for s in t0]
[[('This', 'V'), ('is', 'V'), ('one', 'N'), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')],
  [('And', 'CNJ'), ('This', 'V'), ('is', 'V'), ('another', 'DET'), ('one', 'N')]]
```

Splitting it out into the non-list-comprehension form:

```
def translate(tpl):
    result = []
    t0 = [' '.join([nltk.tag.tuple2str(item) for item in sent]) for sent in tpl]
    for t in t0:
        t = re.sub(r'/NUM', '/N', t)
        t = [nltk.tag.str2tuple(item) for item in t.split()]
        result.append(t)
    return result
```

Comment: Okay, so `t` is now a list. Operate on each element of `t`.

Comment: now when operation on every element i get only the last sentence as before (see **EDIT2** for details)

Comment: still can't work it out. plz put it in a function like on my example(and not in 1 line because I have more than 1 regex which won't fit in 1 line). I'm totally confused...

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just modify it in the original structure though.